# Bootstrap navbar disappears when resizing screen

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout, navbar

My navbar is supposed to collapse to a select-list when the screen is resized below threshold. It works for my home page, but not for the others, i.e. on other pages besides home page, when the screen is resized until the sites collapsed, the navbar disappears completely (the select-list element that's supposed to be there is not there). I have a submenu below my navbar, and it collapses just fine. I wonder what's the problem? Could it be scripts conflict (but collapse is bootstrap css right)?

My navbar is of class navbar, with a logo of tag  at the left and

for the link buttons.

I use jQuery and django alongside bootstrap.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/global.css">
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--[if ie]><meta content='IE=8' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/><![endif]-->
    <link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
    <!--link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"-->      
    <link href="/static/bootstrap/css/paralax.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/static/bootstrap/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <link href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>      
            <script src="js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->




        <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>    
        <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/jquery.scrolltotop.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/highcharts-3/js/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/superfish.js"></script>

    <title>CoAssets Platform (BETA)</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--div class="container-fluid"-->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" id="topmenu">
            {% block topmenu %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid" style="background-color:#ffad37">
            <div class="span12" id="submenu" style="padding-top:2px; padding bottom:2px">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">          
                {% block submenu %}{% endblock %}
                <li class="pull-right"><a class="btn" href="/account/logout" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; text-align: center;">Logout</a>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="/account/">Account</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    <!--/div-->

    <!--div class="container-fluid"-->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" id="main">
                {% block main_body %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div> 
    <!--/div-->
    </br>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="copyright">    
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <p>Legalise</p>
                <p>Contact Us</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <p>Partners</p>
                <p>FAQ</p>
                <p>Definitions</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <p><a  href="/util/">Admin</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid" id="copyright">
            <div class="span12" id="footer">
                <p>Copyright of CoAssets.com &copy; 2013</p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>


<script>
//script conflicts with some other jQuery scripts, so need to handle this script
jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function($){  
    $('.nav li').each(function() {
        var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
        var thisPath = $(this).children().attr('href');
        //alert("sub menu currentPath= "+currentPath+" thisPath= "+thisPath);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        if (thisPath == currentPath && !$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        };
    });

    $('#menu li').each(function() {
        var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
        var thisPath = $(this).children().attr('href');
        var len = thisPath.length;
        //alert("top menu currentPath= "+currentPath+" thisPath= "+thisPath);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        if (thisPath != '/' && thisPath == currentPath.substring(0,len) 
                                                    && !$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else if (thisPath=='/' && currentPath == '/')
        {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        };
    });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>



{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block topbar %}

{% endblock %}

{% block topmenu %}
    <section class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner main-menu">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">
                    <a href="www.ascendantassets.com" class="logo pull-left"><img src="/public_media/index_01 edited4.png" alt=""></a>      
                </div>
                <div class="span10">
                    <nav id="menu" class="pull-right" >
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home<br/><span>CoAssets</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/cms/view/">News</a></li>      
                            <li><a href="/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>                    
                            <li><a href="/property/">Opportunities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/ipo/">New Opportunities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/transaction/">Transaction</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/analytics/npv/">Research</a></li> 
                            <!--li><a href="/account/">Account</a></li-->
                            <!--li><a href="/util/">Admin</a></li-->
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    {%comment%}
    <div class="label label-warning offset2">
        <p>CoAssets Beta</p>
    </div>
    {%endcomment%}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Comment: I suspected conflict at script, so here is my base.html, the missing navbar is basically in the block topmenu

Comment: but it does work at home page only

Comment: I am having the same problem; the menu does not reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap 3.0, `navbar-inner` is no longer a class, and in my case, when experiencing this issue, removing that class resulted in the correct behavior.

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsing-nav">
                <span class="sr-only"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsing-nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <!--   dropdown items go here -->
    </ul>
    </div>

            </div><!--/.navbar -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

alternatively, you could add the following into your style declarations to self-support this

```
.navbar-inner {
   min-height: 50px;
}
```

The issue is cause by a combination of things:

- no text in navbar when in collapsed mode (most common is navbar-brand item)
- this leaves on floated elements in the layout
- removal of `navbar-inner` class from the bootstrap library

the dev team fixed this [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8374), however there are a lot of example pieces of code out there where users who needed to use a nav inside of a `.container`, and recommended using `.navbar-inner`... which no longer exists.

The use of that non-existent class throws off your css because bootstrap compiles the css from less, and that property is assigned to the `.navbar` property, but not `.navbar-inner`, so basically the `min-height` property does not wind up being assigned assigned to your navbar, and you're left with no height on the nav, no text to give the element a calculated height, and only floating elements that are outside of the flow and don't get calculated in height computations.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem , but just I added "position:fixed " for container and it works. Try , maybe it works for you.

Comment: this will disrupt the flow, and cause unintended problems throughout the remainder of your page.